# ASP.NET GridView Paging - Handle Last Page Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I'm trying to make use of asp:GridView's built in paging functionality, but cannot seem to get the "Last Page" button to work when the mode is set to NumericFirstLast.  Here's the code sample:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" 
    PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="15"
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
    <%-- Column Definitions --%>
</asp:GridView>

// C# Behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    // Assign DataSource
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    LoadGrid();
}
```

What's happening is when the last button is being clicked on the pager `e.NewPageIndex` holds a value of -1, meaning the assignment throws an exception.  However, the `GridView1.PageCount` during the index changing event is 0 so I cannot use that to set the page index to count - 1.  Any suggestions as to what is going on with this code or why I am receiving a -1 from the event args?

Comment: ``e.PageIndex = Int32.MaxValue;``

Comment: you may also want to look at :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.mode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, using `Int32.MaxValue` definitely worked! But I can't see anything in the MSDN documentation that states why this works

Comment: if you use this : ``<pagersettings mode="NumericFirstLast"
            firstpagetext="First"
            lastpagetext="Last"
            pagebuttoncount="5"  
            position="Bottom"/>`` you do not need to write any code in Index Changing

Comment: That last comment is incorrect, you need something in the PageIndexChanging event handler to load content.

Comment: there is nothing like that mentioned on MSDN page, so i assume that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I cannot explain why, nor find the answer in MSDN documentation, but as Ehsan suggested in the comments above, when `e.NewPageIndex == -1` if you set `GridView1.PageIndex` to `Int32.MaxValue` it forces the grid to the last page.

If anyone happens to find documentation for why/how this works, please post a comment to that!